# Raycasting only to a particular object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use the following to detect if something is in front of my avatar:

```
void Start()
{
    Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, 10))
        Debug.Log("Something in front");
}
```

Now, I am trying to find out if *only a specific object* is in front, for example another avatar with the name `Police` in the hierarchy:

```
public class CharAnim : MonoBehaviour
{

  police = GameObject.Find("Police");

  void Start()
  {
      Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

      if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, 10))
          Debug.Log("Something in front");
  }

}
```

However, from the documentation, I cannot see if it is possible to use this `police` variable to detect it through ray-casting, measuring distance to it, etc...

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last answer doesn't take into account that things can actually block the raycast from even *reaching* your desired object.

You must first give the object you want to detect a custom [layer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html).

Then you have to shoot a raycast which will *penetrate* and *ignore* all layers except for the desired one, like so:

*Please note: This example assumes you used custom layer #9*:

```
float distance = 10;
int layer = 9;
int layerMask = 1<<layer;

if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, distance, layerMask))
      Debug.Log("Something in front");
```

You really shouldn't mark answers as accepted unless they have actually solved the problem, because questions with answers marked as accepted receive substantially less attention from people who would otherwise potentially be able to solve it for you.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. You are indeed right. I discovered this after I accidentally removed a table that was in between the two objects, blocking the raycast from reaching my intended item. I will try this and comment again if I have any problems. Cheers

Comment: @maksymiuk: could you please explain why `1<<9`changes the ray to collide only with 9? Because when you just use "9" in the Raycast, the 9th layer will be excluded, while "1<<9" excludes all layers expect layer 9.

Comment: Because layers are not read as integers, but as binary. So`9` is actually `00001001` which is actually excluding everything except layer 1 and 4, since the first, and 4th flags are enabled, from right to left. `int i = 1<<9;` is just a human-legible way to show 9th flag in binary, though it can also be written as `int i = 256;` or `int i = 0x100;`

Answer (score 1):

```
RaycastHit hit;

if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, hit,10) && hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "police" )
{
// do stuff here
}
```

Note that you need to set the tag of the gameObject from the editor. you could also use gameObject.name .

Comment: Thank you very much Uri. I placed the following in my `Start` function, but it would not detect anything: `RaycastHit hit; `  `Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward); ` `if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit, 10) && (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Police")) {Debug.Log("yey!");} `I then placed it all in `Update` to see if starting and waking up might be the problem, but still would not... My `Police` avatar is activated at run time, so this game object definitely exists...

Comment: does the avatar have a collider ? Other possibility is that the direction of the raycast is wrong .

Comment: Yes, the avatar has a capsule collider. How can I cover a range, instead of just a forward direction? Is that possible?

Comment: Reading this link :http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.html might be of assistance theese are all the cast types in the Physics class. Another thing might be distance of the Raycast we are doing, perhaps 10 is not enough ?

Comment: I will consider them all. Thank you so much Uri.