# Unity click an object behind other using Raycast

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d-games, raycasting, gameobject

There are many questions like this, but I didn't find a valid solution to my problem.

I would like to click an object behind a collider, this is my code:

```
    void Update () {
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
    }
}
```

I put this code inside the script attached to the first object but the debug log will never be called.
Any ideas?

Comment: This should work... Wait, hold on, are you using 2D physics objects?

Comment: As far as I know, this is only doable if your foreground object is on a separate layer that can then be ignored by the raycast.

Comment: But why, why are you doing this? What type of object is behind the other object. It's likely that the answer to your questions is probably easy if we understand why you are doing this because might be another way to accomplish it.

Comment: @Programmer I'm using a big sphere collider (with isTrigger activated) to see when an enemy enter in a particular zone, my problem was that is worked but when I tried to click the object I hit the collider (so my question was, how can I ignore the first collider?) anyway, xFL gived me a very great solution

Comment: @Draco18s just out of curiosity, why a 2d object could be a problem?

Comment: @JrAntonio It *could* be, as 2D physics objects do not respond to 3D raycasts. They're two entirely different physics systems and they don't interact. But I misread your question and you've got an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want to click on the yellow sphere (see image) and want the name of the white cube?

[image]

There are two possible ways to do that:

**1. Ignore Raycast Layer**

You could give the yellow sphere the unity standard layer "Ignore Raycast":

[image]

Then your code should work (I added the on left mouse click)

```
    void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) // Click on left mouse button
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Use Layer Mask**

See: [Using Layers and Bitmask with Raycast in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559722/using-layers-and-bitmask-with-raycast-in-unity)

If that's not what you're looking for please give further information and a screen shot of your problem.

Comment: I implemented the first solution, it works without code, it just ignore my click on the first object. Thank you!