# Checking if the Raycast hit, hits a layer from the LayerMask?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Title says it al.

Initially I was using:

```
hit.transform.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("Floor")
```

But eventually I figured out I needed different layers for different floors, I figured I should use a LayerMask, please correct me if I'm wrong but can't get it to work.

At the top of the document I have:

```
public LayerMask floorLayers;
```

In the void Update I have:

```
int floorMask = ~floorLayers.value;
```

And in the if statement I have:

```
if (playerHasWetFeet == true && wetSteps < maxWetSteps && controller.isGrounded && hit.transform.gameObject.layer == floorMask)
```

This however isn't working.

Can anyone point me out what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

This is within my update function:

```
int floorMask = ~floorLayers.value;

    currentFrameFootstepLeft = anim.GetFloat("FootstepLeft");

    if (currentFrameFootstepLeft > 0 && lastFrameFootstepLeft < 0)
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, dirDown, out hit, 10f, floorMask))
        {
            if (playerHasWetFeet == true && wetSteps < maxWetSteps && controller.isGrounded && (1 << hit.transform.gameObject.layer & floorMask) != 0)
            {
                LeftWetStepSpawner();
                Debug.Log("Hit");
            }
```

Comment: Is `floorLayers` set to select each floor layer, which makes `floorMask` select everything that isn't a floor? In that case, what happens if you just remove the last part of the `if` statement altogether?

Comment: After some testing I got it to work, but it is inverted. I had selected the 2 layers I want the raycast to hit, but it turns out I had to select everything but the 2 layers I want. Is there a way to invert this?

Comment: Invert the last parameter in your `Raycast` call, or remove the `~` if it is already there.

Comment: That's it, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the raycast to ignore anything that isn't a floor, you can use the mask in the raycast so that it only hits floors. To do this, you want to have your `LayerMask floorLayers` so that only floors are checked, then in your `Raycast`:

#### `Physics.Raycast(transform.position, dirDown, out hit, 10f, ~floorLayers.value)`

If you do this, *any* hit will be a floor hit, and you don't need to do any bit math below.

If you later decide you can't use the same mask for the raycast (maybe you really need the raycast to be able to collide with numerous possible targets *and then see* if the hit object happens to be a floor), then read below.

---

First, you want to compare a mask value that has its bits set to true only for floors, which seems to be `floorLayers.value`.

If you want to compare a `GameObject.layer` to a `LayerMask.value`, you will first need to shift a bit by `GameObject.layer`.

Also, if you want to check for at least one match between `gameObject.layer` and `floorMask`, you want to use binary AND (`&`) and see if it's not 0 (`!= 0` is unnecessary but it can help with readability):

#### `... && (1 << hit.transform.gameObject.layer & floorLayers.value) != 0`

This is because `GameObject.layer` is the *index* of that single layer, but `FloorMask.value` is a bit mask that is based on true/false values of various bits. It's meaningless to compare them directly, without making a conversion first.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately it's still not working though. What I want to achieve is that if it hits any of the layers in the layer mask it should do something, in my case instantiate a prefab.

Comment: @QuincyNorbert I didn't realize there were multiple layers in a single `floorMask`.  If that's the case, and you're putting `floorLayers.value` in `Physics.Raycast`, then isn't **any** hit already meeting that condition?  Anyway, I edited my answer to address a `~LayerMask.value` that includes multiple layers.

Comment: For some reason I still can't get it to work, I'll update the post  with a bit more code to give a sense of how it's setup right now.

Answer (score 3):

With this:

```
if(hit.transform.gameObject.layer == floorMask)
```

You're just comparing the layer hit in the `RaycastHit` result. If this is really what you want and you just want to check what the raycast hit by layer then **do not** do any bitmask operation on the layer.

*Remove this*:

```
int floorMask = ~floorLayers.value;
```

Get the layer Indexes:

```
int floor1 = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Floor1");
int floor2 = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Floor2");
int floor3 = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Floor2");
```

then then just compare the Layer index directly:

```
if (hit.transform.gameObject.layer == floor1)
{

}

if (hit.transform.gameObject.layer == floor2)
{

}

if (hit.transform.gameObject.layer == floor3)
{

}
```

---

While that should fix your problem, the main reason of using layermask is to filter the raycast. When using layermask, you use it to decide which objects the raycast should hit or ignore and if this is what you actually want to do, **do not** compare the layer like you did in your code. Simply find the mask then pass the mask to the raycast function. I am not sure if this is what you want to do but both examples should give you idea on what layer mask is used for.

For example, you want to do a raycast to only objects on the "Floor" layer and don't want the raycast to hit any other object on another layer:

```
int floorLayerIndex = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Floor");

//Check if layer is valid
if (floorLayerIndex == -1)
{
    Debug.LogError("Layer Does not exist");
}
else
{
    //Calculate layermask to Raycast to. (Raycast to "Floor" layer only)
    int layerMask = (1 << floorLayerIndex);

    Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    RaycastHit hit;

    //Raycast with that layer mask
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit, 10, layerMask))
    {

    }
}
```

You can find many other examples on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43559723/3785314) post.