# Unity grounded state is flickering for character. .isGrounded being used but still flickering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The grounded state for my character controller flickers on and off constantly at what seems to be every frame. From what I know, it's supposed to check if the player is grounded through player.isGrounded, but something else is moving it back up.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCharacterController: MonoBehaviour {

    static Animator anim;

    public bool walking;

    public GameObject playerModel, Hero;
    //Transforms
    public Transform playerCam, character, centerPoint;

    private Vector3 moveDirection;

    //character controller declaration
    CharacterController player;

    //Mouse Rotation
    private float rotX, rotY;
    //Mouse Y Position
    public float mouseYPosition = 1f; 
    //Mouse Sensitivity
    public float Sensitivity = 10f;
    //Mouse Zoom
    private float zoom;
    public float zoomSpeed = 2;
    //Clamping Zoom
    public float zoomMin = -2f;
    public float zoomMax = -10f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 5f;
    //Move Front Back left & Right
    private float moveFB, moveLR;   
    //Movement Speed
    public float Speed = 2f;
    //Velocity of Gravity
    public float verticalVelocity;
    //Jump Distance
    public float jumpDist = 5f;
    //Multiple Jumps
    int jumpTimes;
    //To use with Dialogue Manager
    public DialogueManager DiagM;

    public AudioClip jumpSound;
    public AudioClip HurtSound;
    public AudioClip PunchSound;

    AudioSource audioSource;

    //knockback

    public float knockBackForce;
    public float knockBackTime;
    private float knockBackCounter;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()   
    {
        //character controller
        player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<CharacterController> ();

        StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine(character));

        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

        //mouse zoom
        zoom = -3;  
        centerPoint.transform.position = playerCam.transform.position;
        centerPoint.transform.parent = null;
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    IEnumerator MyCoroutine (Transform character)
    {
        if (player.isGrounded == true)

        {
        anim.SetBool("isFalling",false);
        //anim.SetBool("isIdling", true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
        }

    }
    // Update is called once per frame

    void Update ()
    {        
        //Mouse Zoom Input
        zoom += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel") * zoomSpeed;

        if (zoom > zoomMin)
            zoom = zoomMin;
        if (zoom < zoomMax)
            zoom = zoomMax;

        //Mouse Camera Input
        playerCam.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (0, 0, zoom);

        //Mouse Rotation

        rotX += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * Sensitivity;
        rotY -= Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * Sensitivity;      

        //Clamp Camera
        rotY = Mathf.Clamp (rotY, -60f, 60f);
        playerCam.LookAt (centerPoint);
        centerPoint.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (rotY, rotX, 0);

        //Movement Speed
        if (knockBackCounter <= 0)
        {   
            moveDirection = (transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) + (transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
            moveDirection = moveDirection * Speed;
            moveDirection.y = verticalVelocity;

            player.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);



            //Movement Rotation

            centerPoint.position = new Vector3 (character.position.x, character.position.y + mouseYPosition, character.position.z);

            //knockback disable
            //Movement Input

            if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)

            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, centerPoint.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0f);
                Quaternion turnAngle = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(moveDirection.x, 0f, moveDirection.z));
                playerModel.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(playerModel.transform.rotation, turnAngle, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);

                if (player.isGrounded == true)
                {
                    anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
                    anim.Play("Running");
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine(character));
            }

            if (Input.GetButtonDown("LHand"))
            {
                audioSource.PlayOneShot(PunchSound, 1F);
                anim.Play("RPunch");
            }

            if (player.isGrounded == true)
            {
                jumpTimes = 0;
                //verticalVelocity = -Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;
                verticalVelocity = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                verticalVelocity += Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;
                anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
                anim.SetBool("isFalling", true);
            }


            if (jumpTimes < 1)
            {
                if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
                {
                    verticalVelocity += jumpDist;
                    anim.Play("Jump");
                    audioSource.PlayOneShot(jumpSound, 1F);
                    jumpTimes += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            knockBackCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    public void Knockback(Vector3 direction)
    {
        knockBackCounter = knockBackTime;
        anim.Play("Jump");
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(HurtSound, 50F);
        moveDirection = direction * knockBackForce;
        moveDirection.y = knockBackForce;
    }
}
```

It looks like it has to do with the verticalVelocity lines, but so far I have only tried setting verticalVelocity = 0 and that works until I have actually moved the character. What could I change to stop the flickering?

Comment: Add the code you are using to check if the player if grounded or not. There may be the issue.

Comment: I can determine if it is grounded or not by checking the animation parameter "isFalling". It does flicker rapidly.

Answer (score 4):

Probably it is already solved, but the reason for that is that if you are using Character Controller you should apply gravity ALL the time to the character.

When the character collides with a object, it actually enters a little bit inside this object, then Unity pushes the character back away from the object, until it is no longer touching it. At this point, your gravity starts acting again, and re initiziling the cycle.

You need to apply gravity 100% of the time to create enough force to "balance" this fight with the floor. Could be a smaller "gravity" like 1. No need to be your gravity variable.

Also, on top of that, I like to add a "Coyote time", and make my on IsGrounded() method, as follows:

```
    public bool IsGrounded()
{
    return CoyoteTime < CoyoteTimeMax;
}

public void CoyoteControl()
{
    if (CharController.isGrounded)
    {
        CoyoteTime = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        CoyoteTime += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

And then I call the CoyoteControl() on Update(), and I can call IsGrounded() whenever I need. 
On the inspector I usually set the CoyoteTimeMax to 0.1 and it makes falls more smooth.

Answer (score 1):

As per you comment. You should not determine if your player is grounded by checking an animation parameter. The best way is to use a RayCast(). So what you have to do:

1. Create a Layer named `Ground`, and add all the platforms in your
   scene to that layer.
2. Create a bool variable

i.e

```
bool isGrounded;
```

3. Create a function to check if the character is grounded

Something like:

```
bool checkGrounded(){

    return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 2f, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground")));

}
```

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43559722/1773841) you can read about the involved parameters in the Raycast

4. Finally inside the update check if the player is grounded or not

Something like:

```
void Update(){
    isGrounded = checkGrounded();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the isGrounded check can change over the course of the Update() function if you are checking it multiple times. Assigning it to a variable at the beginning of the function may solve the flickering issue.

```
void Update()
{
    bool isGrounded = characterController.isGrounded;
    ...
```